# Create Map of classes in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, class, dictionary

I've got a rendering engine, much like React where I need to store classes rather than instances in an object for compiling.

So for example, I have a `Button` component that I would like to be able to dynamically instantiate. Doing this would be as easy as

```
new components["Button"]
```

For this, I need a list of all possible classes. So I've got a `Dictionary` interface declared like so:

```
interface Dictionary<T> {
    [Key: string]: T;
}
```

This works well, I'm easily able to add objects to this dictionary. Except if I have an object:

```
const components: Dictionary<Component> = {
    Button: Button
}
```

Then I get an error because `Button` is a class, rather than an instance. Here, the issue is, I don't want to define the dictionary as `Dictionary<Function>` because that would mean I allow any function into the dictionary. Specifically, I only want to allow **classes** into the dictionary that **extend** the `Component` class.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *also* need to define the signature of the constructor (which makes sense if you think about it), but you do the following:

```
interface ComponentClass {
    new (a: number): Component;
}
```

(The signature of the constructor is probably not "number", but put in whatever it is.)

Comment: So, have I understood correctly, I would initialise the dictionary like so `Dictionary<ComponentClass>`?

Comment: You would "declare" it like that, yes.

Comment: thank you, I was able to use this answer. This solved my issue. Accepting now.